# cross origin access issues - django 2.1.7

Tags: python, django, cross-domain

I have gone through literally all SO links, reinstalled django and django-cors-headers and followed [this](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/#configuration) to the T and yet we get

> pre flight error cross origin not allowed

Django version 2.1.7

relevant sections of settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'uploads.core',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsPostCsrfMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

Comment: The issue could be on front-end side. It has to set the proper header values while making API call.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but we are already including "crossDomain: true" in the ajax request being made .. besides every SO thread i have been through, puts the onus entirely on the response header generated by the server

Answer (score 4):

CorsMiddleware should be placed as high as possible, especially before any middleware that can generate responses such as Django’s `CommonMiddleware` or Whitenoise’s `WhiteNoiseMiddleware`. If it is not before, **it will not be able to add the CORS headers to these responses**.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [

    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',        # <-- should be at the top

    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsPostCsrfMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i had already tried this :( .. since i saw that it wasn't making any difference i put it back to where it was in the snippet i shared.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue is because the given Django package is for Djangov2.2>
Here you are using 2.1 so it doesn't support it.

You need to manually pass headers from HttpResponse