# Django OSMGeoAdmin Cross Origin Issue

Tags: django, cross-domain, openstreetmap

It's basically this question: [cross origin access issues - django 2.1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54824113/cross-origin-access-issues-django-2-1-7)

But it's still not correctly answered. Is this still a JS thing? Or are we missing something?

**The original question:**

I have gone through literally all SO links, reinstalled django and django-cors-headers and followed [this](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/#configuration) to the T and yet we get

> pre flight error cross origin not allowed

Django version 2.1.7

relevant sections of settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'uploads.core',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsPostCsrfMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

Even with corsheader middlewear at the top, same error code arrives.

```
[Error] Cross-origin redirection to https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/14/4684/6268.png denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: Origin http://localhost:8000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
[Error] Cannot load image http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/14/4684/6268.png due to access control checks.
```

Comment: Does this have something to do with Docker?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the only way is to simply Disable Cross-Origin Security. You can look it up on Google; I'm not sure if you still need CORS middlewear for production (i.e. hosted, deployed, served via url) however.